# Creating a column from another column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to have a SQLAlchemy `Column` that would be computed from another column. For example, column `month` (`{'Jan', ...}`) from column `date` (like `2014-09-12`), so technically it's a one-time parsing of `09` to `Sep`.

Is it possible to write this into the class of the object itself? Or just run updates each time records get updated?

PS: Months are taken just for example. I'm interested in a general case when the space of the derived column is infinite.

Comment: Do you need the derived column to be stored in the underlying database? (@van's answer seems like the right one if so.) Or do you just need it to be visible from SQLAlchemy? (In which case mine may be easiest.)

Comment: Thanks, Dan! Assuming, you need to store it in the database, another important consideration is: will you be using this column for `filtering/aggregation`? Because if you do, you would like to have indices on them as well.

Comment: Also a good point, van. I would, however, caution that one is liable to be smote by the Database Normalization Deities if one creates tables which [contain columns dependent on non-key columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#.22Nothing_but_the_key.22).

Comment: Fair enough. However I found that persisting computed columns for fields like `YEAR` or `MONTH` of a `date(time)` column is of tremendous value when there is a lot of quering/filtering based on respective `function`.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

Answer (score 8):

[`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property) may meet your needs. This allows you to create something that looks and acts like a normal mapped object column, but is calculated automatically from other columns.

[Example:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#using-column-property-for-column-level-options)

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # actual database columns
    firstname = Column(String(50))   
    lastname = Column(String(50))

    # calculated from the other two
    fullname = column_property(firstname + " " + lastname)
```

In your example usage:

```
class Foo(Base):
    date = Column(DateTime)
    month_only = column_property(date.strptime("%b")) # 'Jan','Feb',etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I tried the last solutions, and it returns `AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'strptime'`. The same for other methods, like `split()`, on `Column`, even if the column contains `String` object. I.e. `column_property(date)` works and `column_property(date.strptime("%b"))` doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Using database level triggers sounds like the most efficient solution to me. Read [`Triggered Columns`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html?highlight=server#triggered-columns) for configuring such columns properly on the `ORM` side.

Comment: Thanks, van. Docs say that `FetchedValue` is a marker, but how can I set the value for the column marked by `FetchedValue`?

Comment: You create a database level trigger (`ON INSERT', `ON UPDATE`) to do that, and `sqlalchemy` will know to fetch new value any time it issues an update/insert for that object (row).